# Extract content of ids with BeautifulSoup Python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have some html pages that should have 1 table, some rows and 2 columns, I'm trying to convert these to cvs tables. I thought to loop through the rows and get the columns however I can't get only the part inside the ids (e.g. id="(-) Additional deductions of AT1 Capital due to Article 3 CRR"). Is there a way just to extract the content of id for each row?

**code**

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

definitions=[]

file = '/Users/tom/Downloads/Capitalresourceitemlevel1.html'

soup = BeautifulSoup(open(file), "html.parser")

table = soup.find_all('table')

for i in table:
    rows = i.find_all('tr')

for i in rows:
    row_tds = i.find_all('td')
    if len(row_tds) == 2:
        definitions.append((row_tds[0].text, row_tds[1].text))
    
with open('output.csv', 'w') as f:
    for line in definitions:
        f.write(','.join(line))
        f.write('\n')
```

**html**

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<style>
        /*
        Colors
        #ffffff
        #333333
        #f2f2f2;
        #dddddd;
        */


        @media all
        {
        html
        {
        font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
        font-size: 14px;
        line-height: 1.428571429;
        color: #333333;
        margin: 0;
        background-color: #ffffff;
        }

        header
        {
        font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
        font-size: 36px;
        border-top: 4px solid transparent;
        border-right: 4px solid transparent;
        border-left: 4px solid transparent;
        border-bottom: 2px solid #f2f2f2;
        }

        header:after
        {
        content: "Style: technical";
        font-size: 22px;
        }

        body
        {
        font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
        font-size: 11px;
        line-height: 1.428571429;
        color: #333333;
        margin: 20;
        background-color: #ffffff;
        }

        .footer
        {
        page-break-after: always;
        }

        @page:right{
        @bottom-left {
        margin: 10pt 0 30pt 0;
        border-top: .25pt solid #666;
        content: "My book";
        font-size: 9pt;
        color: #333;
        }
        }

        li span
        {
        font-size: 18px;
        }

        h1
        {
        font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
        font-size: 24px;
        font-weight: normal;
        }

        a:focus=""
        {
        outline: thin dotted;
        }

        a:link
        {
        text-decoration: none;
        }

        a:active,
        a:hover
        {
        text-decoration: underline;
        outline: 0;
        }

        table {
        border-collapse: collapse;
        border-spacing: 0;
        border: 2px solid transparent;
        width: 99%;
        margin-left:0px;
        margin-right:0px;
        margin-bottom: 50px;
        }


        caption
        {
        caption-side: top;
        }

        th
        {
        text-align: left;
        height: 50px;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
        font-weight: normal;
        font-size: 18px;
        white-space: normal;
        word-wrap:break-word;
        }


        td
        {
        text-align: left;
        padding: 8px;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
        }

        #descriptionvalue
        {
        margin-top: 20px;
        margin-bottom: 50px;
        font-size: 18px;
        }


        #Welcome
        {
        font-size: 18px;
        height:95%;
        }


        div.FalseTableHeader
        {
        border: 2px solid #dddddd;
        border-bottom: 0px solid transparent;
        border-top-right-radius: 0.6em;
        border-top-left-radius: 0.6em;
        background-color: #f2f2f2;
        margin-bottom: 0px;
        height: 50px;
        /*width: 98%;*/
        position: relative
        }

        p.FalseTableHeader
        {
        font-size: 18px;
        padding-top: 0px;
        padding-bottom: 0px;
        margin: 0;
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        transform: translate(0,-70);
        }

        .TableContainer
        {
        margin-top: 0px;
        border: 2px solid #dddddd;
        border-bottom-right-radius: 0.6em;
        border-bottom-left-radius: 0.6em;
        overflow-x: auto;

        }
        #breadcrumbs
        {
        font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
        font-size: 14px;
        font-style: normal;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
        border-top-left-radius: 0.6em;
        }

        .float_center {
        float: right;
        position: relative;
        left: -50%;
        text-align: left;
        }

        .float_center &gt; .child {
        position: relative;
        left: 50%;
        }

        .footer
        {
        display: block;
        background-color: #f2f2f2;
        border: 2px solid #dddddd;
        font-size: 14px;
        height: 22px;
        padding: 10px 15px;
        margin-top: 20px;
        margin-left:0px;
        width: 98%;
        }

        .footer  .copyright
        {
        float:left;
        padding-left: 0px;
        }

        .footer  .date
        {
        float:right;
        padding-right: 0px;
        }


        }




        @media screen
        {
        }




        @media print
        {

        @page {size: A4;}
        .footer {page-break-after: always;}
        #Welcome {font-size: 18px;  height:auto;}

        }
      </style>
<head>
<title>Bank of England</title>
</head>
<header>
<img class="site_logo" src="data:image/gif;base64,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 lRxRRaFC2IEP8xhgggXGmjABQEEyGCHW1yJoY4VWhRySCLx8sCLThKI5AVuXlAkDg1o4KBIKqusMiAAOw=="/>
<div>Stress Test Data Framework Dictionary 2021: Version 02</div>
</header>
<body>
<div></div>
<p id="breadcrumbs">&gt;<a href="..\..\..\Home.html" xmlns="">Home</a>&gt;<a href="..\..\..\Contents\Contents.html" xmlns="">Contents</a>&gt;<a href="..\..\..\Contents\Enumerations\Enumerations.html" xmlns="">Enumerations</a>&gt;<a href="..\..\..\Contents\Enumerations\Capitalresourceitemlevel1\Capitalresourceitemlevel1.html" xmlns="">Capitalresourceitemlevel1</a></p>
<h1 id="..\..\..\Contents\Enumerations\Capitalresourceitemlevel1\Capitalresourceitemlevel1.html" xmlns="">Capitalresourceitemlevel1</h1>
<p class="TableContainer" xmlns="">
<table id="table1">
<tr>
<th>Enumeration</th>
<th>Definition</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td id="(-) Additional deductions of AT1 Capital due to Article 3 CRR" text="">(-) Additional deductions of AT1 Capital due to Article 3 CRR</td>
<td id="" text="">COREP CA1 ID1.1.2.11</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td id="(-) Additional deductions of CET1 Capital due to Article 3 CRR" text="">(-) Additional deductions of CET1 Capital due to Article 3 CRR</td>
<td id="" text="">COREP CA1 ID1.1.1.27</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td id="(-) Additional deductions of T2 Capital due to Article 3 CRR" text="">(-) Additional deductions of T2 Capital due to Article 3 CRR</td>
<td id="" text="">COREP CA1 ID1.2.12</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td id="(-) Amount exceeding the 17.65% threshold" text="">(-) Amount exceeding the 17.65% threshold</td>
<td id="" text="">COREP CA1 ID1.1.1.25</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td id="(-) AT1 instruments of financial sector entities where the institution does not have a significant investment" text="">(-) AT1 instruments of financial sector entities where the institution does not have a significant investment</td>
<td id="" text="">COREP CA1 ID1.1.2.6</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td id="(-) AT1 instruments of financial sector entities where the institution has a significant investment" text="">(-) AT1 instruments of financial sector entities where the institution has a significant investment</td>
<td id="" text="">COREP CA1 ID1.1.2.7</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td id="(-) CET1 instruments of financial sector entities where the institution does not have a significant investment" text="">(-) CET1 instruments of financial sector entities where the institution does not have a significant investment</td>
<td id="" text="">COREP CA1 ID1.1.1.22</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td id="(-) CET1 instruments of financial sector entities where the institution has a significant investment" text="">(-) CET1 instruments of financial sector entities where the institution has a significant investment</td>
<td id="" text="">COREP CA1 ID1.1.1.24</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td id="(-) Deductible deferred tax assets that rely on future profitability and arise from temporary differences" text="">(-) Deductible deferred tax assets that rely on future profitability and arise from temporary differences</td>
<td id="" text="">COREP CA1 ID1.1.1.23</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td id="(-) Deferred tax assets that rely on future profitability and do not arise from temporary differences net of associated tax liabilities" text="">(-) Deferred tax assets that rely on future profitability and do not arise from temporary differences net of associated tax liabilities</td>
<td id="" text="">COREP CA1 ID1.1.1.12</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td id="(-) Equity exposures under an internal models approach which can alternatively be subject to a 1250% risk weight" text="">(-) Equity exposures under an internal models approach which can alternatively be subject to a 1250% risk weight</td>
<td id="" text="">COREP CA1 ID1.1.1.21</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td id="(-) Excess of deduction from AT1 items over AT1 Capital" text="">(-) Excess of deduction from AT1 items over AT1 Capital</td>
<td id="" text="">COREP CA1 ID1.1.1.16</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td id="(-) Excess of deduction from T2 items over T2 Capital" text="">(-) Excess of deduction from T2 items over T2 Capital</td>
<td id="" text="">COREP CA1 ID1.1.2.8</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td id="(-) Free deliveries which can alternatively be subject to a 1250% risk weight" text="">(-) Free deliveries which can alternatively be subject to a 1250% risk weight</td>
<td id="" text="">COREP CA1 ID1.1.1.19</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td id="(-) Goodwill" text="">(-) Goodwill</td>
<td id="" text="">COREP CA1 ID1.1.1.10</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td id="(-) IRB shortfall of credit risk adjustments to expected losses" text="">(-) IRB shortfall of credit risk adjustments to expected losses</td>
<td id="" text="">COREP CA1 ID1.1.1.13</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td id="(-) Other intangible assets" text="">(-) Other intangible assets</td>
<td id="" text="">COREP CA1 ID1.1.1.11</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td id="(-) Positions in a basket for which an institution cannot determine the risk weight under the IRB approach, and can alternatively be subject to a 1250% risk weight" text="">(-) Positions in a basket for which an institution cannot determine the risk weight under the IRB approach, and can alternatively be subject to a 1250% risk weight</td>
<td id="" text="">COREP CA1 ID1.1.1.20</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td id="(-) Qualifying holdings outside the financial sector which can alternatively be subject to a 1250% risk weight" text="">(-) Qualifying holdings outside the financial sector which can alternatively be subject to a 1250% risk weight</td>
<td id="" text="">COREP CA1 ID1.1.1.17</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td id="(-) Reciprocal cross holdings in AT1 Capital" text="">(-) Reciprocal cross holdings in AT1 Capital</td>
<td id="" text="">COREP CA1 ID1.1.2.5</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td id="(-) Reciprocal cross holdings in CET1 Capital" text="">(-) Reciprocal cross holdings in CET1 Capital</td>
<td id="" text="">COREP CA1 ID1.1.1.15</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td id="(-) Reciprocal cross holdings in T2 Capital" text="">(-) Reciprocal cross holdings in T2 Capital</td>
<td id="" text="">COREP CA1 ID1.2.7</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td id="(-) Securitisation positions which can alternatively be subject to a 1250% risk weight" text="">(-) Securitisation positions which can alternatively be subject to a 1250% risk weight</td>
<td id="" text="">COREP CA1 ID1.1.1.18</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td id="(-) T2 instruments of financial sector entities where the institution does not have a significant investment" text="">(-) T2 instruments of financial sector entities where the institution does not have a significant investment</td>
<td id="" text="">COREP CA1 ID1.2.8</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td id="(-) T2 instruments of financial sector entities where the institution has a significant investment" text="">(-) T2 instruments of financial sector entities where the institution has a significant investment</td>
<td id="" text="">COREP CA1 ID1.2.9</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td id="(-)Defined benefit pension fund assets" text="">(-)Defined benefit pension fund assets</td>
<td id="" text="">COREP CA1 ID 1.1.1.14</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td id="10% CET1 threshold" text="">10% CET1 threshold</td>
<td id="" text="">COREP CA4 ID9</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td id="17.65% CET1 threshold" text="">17.65% CET1 threshold</td>
<td id="" text="">COREP CA4 ID10</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td id="Accumulated other comprehensive income" text="">Accumulated other comprehensive income</td>
<td id="" text="">COREP CA1 ID1.1.1.3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td id="Additional Tier 1 Capital" text="">Additional Tier 1 Capital</td>
<td id="" text="">COREP CA1 ID1.1.2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td id="Adjustments to CET1 due to prudential filters" text="">Adjustments to CET1 due to prudential filters</td>
<td id="" text="">COREP CA1 ID1.1.1.9</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td id="Adjustments to total own funds" text="">Adjustments to total own funds</td>
<td id="" text="">
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td id="AT1 capital elements or deductions - other" text="">AT1 capital elements or deductions - other</td>
<td id="" text="">COREP CA1 ID1.1.2.12</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td id="Capital instruments and subordinated loans eligible as T2 Capital" text="">Capital instruments and subordinated loans eligible as T2 Capital</td>
<td id="" text="">COREP CA1 ID1.2.1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td id="Capital instruments eligible as AT1 Capital" text="">Capital instruments eligible as AT1 Capital</td>
<td id="" text="">COREP CA1 ID1.1.2.1</td>
</tr>
</table>
</p>
<div class="footer" xmlns=""><span class="copyright">
        Copyright: Bank Of England</span><span class="float_center">
        PageNo:298</span><span class="date">
        Created: 2021-01-18 00:00:00</span></div>
</body>
<footer></footer>
</html>
```

Comment: `.find_all('td')` returns a list of elements. To get the id attribute of each element, you just index by the key, e.g., `[e["id"] for e in i.find_all('td')]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about replacing the last line with one of:

- `definitions.append([td.text for td in i.find_all('td')])`
- `definitions.append([td['id'] for td in i.find_all('td')])` (per @Justin Ezequiel's comment)

This will get either the `text` or the value of `id` for each one

EDIT per comment:
This is how you could do it, basically you need to save a tuple of the text of both items in each `td`.
The second part is one way to write it to a file

```
for i in rows:
    row_tds = i.find_all('td')
    if len(row_tds) == 2:
        definitions.append((row_tds[0].text, row_tds[1].text))
    
with open('output.csv', 'w') as f:
    for line in definitions:
        f.write(','.join(line))
        f.write('\n')
```

Comment: Thanks. The problem with this is that it makes it tricky to distinguish the 2 columns which I need to generate my cvs output file. I would like to find a 'clean' way to parse the html files and generate 1 csv file for each with 2 columns (as per html table).

Comment: see the edited answer if this is what you are looking for. I would be tempted to save each part of the tuple in `definitions` as keys & values in a dictionary since this is what it really is.

Comment: Thanks a lot however when I try it it throws me an error 'TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, Tag found'.

Comment: Do you get this error when writing to csv? Are you sure you specified `.text` for both items that you appended to `definitions`?

Comment: yes I only get the error in the 'with open' section. The items in definitions are text

Comment: Please post the full code. I can run mine and I get the expected output minus a small tweak that you should be able to find, but no error

Comment: Updated in the original question for ease of reference

Comment: Besides the fact that you forgot to define `definitions`, the code works as is

Comment: I just realised that the f.write(','.join(line)) part creates some issue when you have commas in the sentences in the first column

Comment: I made a slight correction, I created another list for the second column and changed the section for the csv code